# How to communicate with a background service

Tags: java, android

I have developed an Android music player, but there is one thing I am struggling with. I have headphones with a media button. With help from various posts such as [this](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Android_Broadcast_Intents_and_Broadcast_Receivers#An_Overview_of_Broadcast_Intents) and [this](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=415) I have a RemoteControlReceiver which can successfully respond to the button being pressed with a Toast. What I need is for the BroadcastReciever to communicate with my Activity or, even better, the background music service (which is bound to the Activity).

The relevant bits of the project (apologies if it's a bit confused - I've been trying so many options) are:

In my manifest:

```
<!-- Broadcast Receivers -->
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter android:priority="1000000000" >
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In RemoteControlReceiver.class:

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    // Constructor is mandatory
    public RemoteControlReceiver ()
    {
        super ();
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);

            if (event == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "ACTION_DOWN PRESSED!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my activity:

```
private final RemoteControlReceiver myReceiver = new RemoteControlReceiver();

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // Media button on headphones
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    registerReceiver(myReceiver, filter);
}

public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    unregisterReceiver(myReceiver);
}
```

I've tried adding this to RemoteControlReceiver.class:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("action", "togglePlay");
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and then in my MainActivity/OnCreate:

```
// Pick up extras passed by BroadcastReceiver
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
    String action = extras.getString("action","");
    Toast.makeText(context, "Action="+action, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    clickAction(action);
}
```

The Toast confirms this is working, BUT... this starts a new activity instead of communicating with the existing activity. I've also tried this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
myIntent.putExtra("action", "togglePlay");
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(myIntent);
```

but the Toast is not displayed (I assume because FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP means OnCreate is not passed?).

My question is not so much "what am I doing wrong" (to which I'm sure the answer is "where do we start?") but really "what is the correct way to get my service to respond to the media button being pressed"?

Comment: I suggest you think of your problem more generically. The media button and/or musicplayer bit doesn't really matter, does it? The problem you're trying to solve is communicating between an activity or broadcast-receiver and a service. You could use an eventbus such as Otto, or send messages to the service's looper via a handler.

Comment: Try to override onNewIntent in activity.

Comment: Thanks @323go - plenty of food for thought. Have reworded the summary to focus on the real issue. My service doesn't currently have a looper but what I've just read about it sounds promising, so read up on that and see where it gets me. I'll also take a look at Otto

Comment: Thanks @dtx12 - I wasn't aware of onNewIntent. It has proved very useful in my app, and has solved another problem I was having. Unless I'm mistaken though I can't use this in a service, so will pursue 323go's suggestions as well.

Comment: @323go - I've had a look at Loopers and Handlers and can see how this can be used to pass messages between an Activity and a bound Service, but I cannot see how I can use this technique to pass a message from  a BroadcastReceiver (where I cannot, for instance, use bindService). Any further pointers would be much appreciated.